# How is a query used in a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I would really like to know if the query field will update on the report just as it does on the query itself. In other words, when I update a material price on the query, will it also update when the report is run?

Comment: How are you using the 'query' with the report?  Are you using the Database Expert, a Command, or assigning a data table in code?

Comment: Database expert. We would be plopping a field on to an invoice report. Obviously, we need correct material pricing on invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refresh the report (`F5`), the field's values will be refreshed.

If you select `Databae | Verify Database`, the field's definition will be updated.